# how to get access to records using Controller? Odoo 10

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to return products information via json using Controllers.

Here is what I try

```
class api_test(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/test', type='json', auth='public')
    def index2(self, **args):
        p = self.env['product.template'].search_read([], ['name'])
        return json.dumps(p)
```

But I get this error message

```
'api_test' object has no attribute 'env'
```

How can I get that Info without using json-rpc?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! I used http.request.env inside odoo module.

```
class api_test(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/test', type='json', auth='public')
    def index2(self, **args):
        p = http.request.env['product.template'].sudo().search_read([], ['name'])
        return json.dumps(p)
```